# Crontab Centos Run Perl every 2 Minutes

Tags: linux, centos, redhat

i have a server RHEL 7 where i must run a script "perl" in every 2 minutes , all hour , all day , all week .

so i made theses steps ,

```
nano /etc/crontab
```

and inserted this command below .

```
2**** projop /web/projop/packages/intranet-helpdesk/perl/./import-pop3.perl
```

But is not running . this is my full crontab :

```
    SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,$
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
#29 3 * * * /root/bin/export-dbs > /var/log/postgres/export-dbs.log 2>&1
#24 3 * * * /usr/bin/find /export/backup -name '*.tgz' -mtime +6 | xargs rm
#25 3 * * * /usr/bin/find /export/backup -name '*.bz2' -mtime +6 | xargs rm
2**** projop /web/projop/packages/intranet-helpdesk/perl/./import-pop3.perl
```

someone could help me ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If projop is a command call to a program with +x right and referenced into the PATH or profile or bashrc, be sure about this command and try to test it.

```
2 * * * * projop /web/projop/packages/intranet-helpdesk/perl/./import-pop3.perl
```

regards